# Change default repository in ivy for everything using ivy

Tags: ant, repository, artifactory, ivy

I have an environment where (basically) all dependencies of anything built need to be pulled from our artifactory repository, and at the same time many 3rd party libraries need to be built from source (usually with very minor automated changes) and stored in the repository to be used as a dependency in the future. The reason this is done is outside of my control and not something that can be changed. I am looking for the best way to point these 3rd party libraries to our repository after pulling their source from github or wherever, starting with anything using ivy (not everything is using ivy, at a minimum maven and gradle are used as well, but ivy is used a lot, so starting there).

I have read up a fair bit on the ivy options for changing the default repository for one project ([Here](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/defaultconf.html) and other sites), but want to try and do a more wide-scale solution which could save a lot of time in the long run. One option I thought of would be to modify the ivysettings-public.xml file so the default ivy public repository is actually our artifactory. Two issues I see with this are its possible for a project to have set a specific repository to check before the default public one, though I don't know how common that is. Also this might require building ivy from source? Not an impossible task, just extra work, though I'm again not sure if it will or won't. But I'm pretty sure I know (or could easily figure out) how to do what is needed for this solution.

Another possible option would be to have some type of module or middle man that attaches to ivy and intercepts repository requests, redirecting them to our artifactory. This one I'm not actually sure if its possible or not, but it seems like it might be.

I know there might be some environment variables or ANT properties that could be set before the build call that might also work (from the same link as before). This isn't quite as ideal but is still much better then changing the ivysettings.xml file for each project.

Basically the end goal of this would be that we could pull a project from github that uses ivy, build it with no changes to the code, and have all dependency calls look at our artifactory repository. This would also be done with things that use maven or gradle and so on, but it seemed that a one size fits all solution is either not possible or more work then it's worth (I could always be wrong though), so starting with ivy. I feel like my first idea is the best combination of time saving and feasibility, but I know just enough to know that it's likely there's a better option.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to bother with default repository. I see that in that page you've linked that terminology might seem confusing to someone new to ivy. These are just some types of repositories, but nothing you need to be concerned with.

Only thing you need to do is to set up a [chained resolver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/chain.html) in the ivysettings.xml. Within that chained resolver you can add as many (sub)resolvers as you want, one of them can be you artifactory, the other some public repository (like maven central), third some local filesystem resolver for testing etc... Whenever you use ivy, just tell it to use this chained resolver, or make it a default one in ivysettings.

Of course when publishing you ivy modules, make sure to use one of the child/sub resolvers, I'm guessing you would use on pointing to an ivy repo in your artifactory.

Comment: Are you talking about the main ivysettings file used by ivy itself, or the ivysettings file for each project? You are correct that I am new to ivy, but I've read up a bit and think I understand how to set up a chained resolver for an ivy project, or how to use iBiblio for a specific repository, among other options. But I'm hoping to find an option that will allow any ivy based project to use our artifactory with no modifactions. If you are talking about the core ivysettings.xml file, then that does come back to the issue of can I modify that without building ivy from source?

Comment: There are no main, or core ivy setting.xml filles. There are some default settings ivy uses of course (and maybe they are stored in an ivy file distributed with ivy itself, or for example an IDE). What you need to do is simply write an ivy settings.xml and use it (from ant for example)

Comment: So if I write up a ivysettings file in the manner I want, then can I force it to be used form an ant build call ("ant package" and such) or do I have to replace the projects settings file with my own first? In [solr](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr) for example there is top-level-ivy-settings.xml and default-nested-ivy-settings.xml (both under the lucene folder). It looks like if I just replaced the second file with my own of the same name it would work. But I can't replace the first because it also points to version info as well as repository info. (continued)

Comment: (from previous) So in this case a direct file replacement can work after finding the right file, but I'm not sure that will always work. Finding the file to replace in each ivy project is ok, doesn't add too much work, but if the file might have other code that is needed that's a problem, as each pulled project would need to have an individually created ivy file which is what I'm hoping to avoid.

Comment: Ok, so each project does have it's own ivy.xml (the module descriptor), it must. However ivysettings.xml can be used for all the projects. For example I have N java projects and they all use the same settings. I just make an env var where I set the path to ivysettings.xml and then use that in each of my build.xmls with `ivysettings` ant task. So yes, you can use or force as you put it any ivyseetings to be used. In solr example, they have ivysettings for publishing internally (like what you need) and for publishing to mvncentral for example (TLDR), but you don't  need all that --next comment

Comment: --continued-from-previous based on what you wrote. So again, you just need on ivyseetings, write a chain resolver, and then in (other) projects' buld.xmls use that ivysettings and publish to any subresolver you need (probably the one pointing to your artifactory). In the case of solr,you will have to change the build.xml file, or write a new one, where you would need to publish to your ivy artifactor repo, because in there it's publishing to maven.

Comment: So this is all running into the same issue of being very hard to automate, which is my goal. Ideally I would get to a point where I could just change the github target form one ivy based project to a different one, and not change the anything else in the script, and it would build the new project correctly with our artifactory as the main or only repository. I know ideal doesn't always happen but I'm trying to get as close to that as possible. So something that is a more general modification is what I'm trying to find (hence looking at editing core settings of ivy among other options).

Comment: YEs, not easy, but you want to publish everything (3rd party and your own projects) to your ivy artifactory repo, and without telling each of these projects where this repo is, that's not possible :)

Comment: Well I want to tell them where it is, was just hoping I could do that on a wide scale. Replacing some or all of the default ivy-settings files (public, shared, etc) with my own files that point where I want would work for most cases (except when a project doesn't use those at all), just a bit time consuming and higher risk of problems. Find/replacing the lines in each projects ivy file that points to the default repositories would also potentially work in most cases, though still not perfect. I was hoping to find a more ideal way of doing it, but its seeming like there might not be one.

Comment: I think you're still missing the point. You just need 1 ivysettings.xml, but you do need to replace or write new build.xmls tellign the to use only your one ivysettings.xml

Comment: But that means having to make specific build.xml files for every project (or make specific edits that can't be easily automated), which adds a large amount of time if the number of projects gets high. I'm looking for a method that does not involve making a different file for each project. Either no modifications to source at all, or modifications that are easy to automate (replacing text that most ivy based projects will have, either in the build.xml or the ivysettings.xml or wherever, or replacing a file with one pre-set file that is the same for all). Abnormal, but what I'm looking for.